Set a variable from a json file and get a second API json
I have an API URL that I need to get another API URL from and then use that json file to create my html page.
I can fetch the first json file at, let us say, http://www.thiscarsite.com/API/thecars and it is set up similar to the following example.
{ "manufacturer": "Cheverolet",
  "model": "Camaro",
  "year": "1990",
  "styles": {
        "top": "convertible",
        "engine"; "v8",
        "address": "http://www.somesite.com/api/90ChevCamConvV8"
        }
}

I can get the first json information with fetch/await or something as simple as this.
const startUrl = 'http://www.thiscarsite.com/API/thecars';
fetch(startUrl)
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });

I have seen examples where one gets the URL by const newURL = data.styles.address;. How do I get the address from the example above AND request the second json file?
I failed to mention that the URL in the first json file can change 3 or 4 times per week. Thus, the need to get it from the first one every time I need to access it.
Tried something like this. My edits to insert the second URL resulted in a failure.
fetch('https://example.com/endpoint1')
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data1 => {
    return fetch(`https://example.com/endpoint2?data=${data1}`);
  })
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data2 => {
    console.log(data2);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });

Also, tried using two async functions but get errors like "response already called" (or something to the effect).

I figured out what I was doing wrong. Or at least how my thinking was wrong. I didn't realize that "response" could be called anything and was trying to use it twice. So, now I have something like this
async function getUrl(){
const response = await fetch(startUrl, {headers: myheader});
const data = await response.json();
console.log(data);
const newUrl = data.styles.address;
const response2 = await fetch(newUrl);
const data2 = await response2.json();
console.log(data2);
}
getUrl();

